# How a particular composition of molecules result into life in form of cell?

Tags: cell-biology

I had read biology in childhood only, but as far as I can remember every living thing/being is made up of cells in the lowest level. Cells again are made up of some particular composition of molecules. But my question is how a particular composition of molecules become alive? Or What's that which turn compositions of molecules sentient?  I'm trying to understand when or how insentient compositions of molecules become sentient.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I don't think one can answer this question differently than giving an entire intro course to molecular biology. I am voting to close as too broad.

Comment: For ressources, have a look at [Books for beginners](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/books-for-beginners)

Comment: Okay @Remi.b Can you answer that in 1 or more comments? I don't want thorough answer or suggest me the proper SE where I can ask this question.

Comment: Taking a biological course is highly impractical just to know the answer. :)

Comment: I suspect you might expect a magical simple answer but there is no such thing to this question. There is no essence of life or any specific process that transform non-living matter into living matter. There is just matter interacting in a complex manner that end up making some entities that we like to call life.

Answer (score 3):

Science does not have an answer to how the first reproducing cell came about.  The actual event has left no traces except life as we see it today. There are theories about parts of how it *might* have happened, but evidence about it essentially doesn't exist.  If you want to get a flavor of recent ideas of scientists in this area, [here is a video of a lecture on "The Origin of Cellular Life on Earth"](https://www.ibiology.org/evolution/origin-of-life/#part-1).